# Change class depending of the page. jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to add an attribute "selected" to a button. It's a group of 5 buttons but I just want one of them to be "selected" according to the page title.

This is what I have: http://jsfiddle.net/M6Ypu/

```
<ul id="menu">
                    <li>
                        <a id="Home" class="selected" href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a id="categories" class href="#">Categories</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a id="franchise" class href="#">Franchise</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a id="about" class href="#">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a id="contact" class href="#">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

Those are in a Master Page for ASP.NET and I want to change the class of the buttons so if I am at categories.aspx the class for a#categories is changed to "selected".

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could make it work by adding a script to the pages using the Master Page

Home page has this code and the selector changes depending on the page I am:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('a.selected').removeClass();
        $('a#Home').addClass("selected");
    });
</script>
```

Since there were only 5 pages, it was much easier to just add the script to each one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("ul#menu a").click(function(){
    $("ul#menu a").each(function(){
      $(this).removeClass('selected');
    });  
  $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});
});
```

#### Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/M6Ypu/3/